# Dynamic JSON handling in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I've got two JSON arrays, one for headers and the other for data. I'm handling the headers, and I'm trying to display the data with respect to those headers using nested ng-repeat, but it results in empty rows. 
The JSON arrays and the html code for displaying the data are pasted below.

Please help me.

```
 $scope.data=[{'first_name':'ruth','last_name':'vick','email':'ruthvick@gmail.com','isMarried':'no','nick_name':'ruthu'},{'first_name':'rahul','last_name':'kumar','email':'rahul@gmail.com','isMarried':'no','nick_name':'rahul'},{'first_name':'vicky','last_name':'gupta','email':'vicky@gmail.com','isMarried':'no','nick_name':'vicky'}]

$scope.headerAll=[{'field':'first_name', 'displayName':'First name','type':'required'},{'field':'last_name', 'displayName':'Last Name','type':'required'},{'field':'email', 'displayName':'Email','type':'required'},{'field':'isMarried', 'displayName':'marital Status','type':'optional'},{'field':'nick_name', 'displayName':'Nick Name','type':'optional'}]


<div>   
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead class="wrapper">
            <tr>
                <th ng-repeat="data in header">
                    <div class="col-md-9">{{data.displayName}}</div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <button href=""   ng-click="deleteColumn(data.field,$index)"><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-trash pull-right"> </span></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dropdown col-md-1" >
                      <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-click = "toPoint($index);">
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                      </button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" ng-repeat="optionalHeader in optional">
                        <li role="presentation" ng-repeat="dataEdit in headerAll"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="" ng-click="editColumn(data.field,dataEdit.field,$index)">{{dataEdit.displayName}}</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th><div class="dropdown" >
                      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Add Columns
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                      </button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" ng-repeat="optionalHeader in optional">
                        <li role="presentation" ng-repeat="optionalHeader in optional"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="" ng-click="addColumn(optionalHeader.field)">{{optionalHeader.displayName}}</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                </th>

            </tr>
        </thead>

      <tbody >
        <tr class="active" ng-repeat="row in data">
            <td ng-repeat="fields in headerAll">
              {{row.fields.field}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody> 
    </table>
</div>
```

Here, row.fields.field is creating empty rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to access with braces and not the dot operator.

data:

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in data">
{{ obj["first_name"]}}
{{ obj["last_name"]}}
</div>
```

header

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in headerAll">
{{ obj["field"]}}
{{ obj["displayname"]}}
</div>
```

Comment: Just to add to this, in your body you want to call `{{row[fields.field]}}`